# Xmind: delete element in a xmind file

Tags: python

I am trying to delete an element within an `xmind` file. I am using the python `sdk` provided by `Xmind` : https://github.com/xmindltd/xmind-sdk-python

The file I want to modify is organized in different levels:

```
rootTopic
level1
level2
leafElement
```

I want to remove duplicate `leafElements`.

So I parse the file and I find the elements I want to remove. Then I call this function:

```
def removeexistingissue(issue):

w = xmind.load(readXmind.filename)
s1 = w.getPrimarySheet()
r1 = s1.getRootTopic()

for sst in r1.getSubTopics():
    for sst1 in sst.getSubTopics():
        for sst2 in sst1.getSubTopics():


            if (str(issue)) in str(sst2.getTitle()):
                text = str(issue)
                sst2.removePosition()
                print "Issue ", text , "removed."
try:
    xmind.save(w, readXmind.filename)
except:
    print "**** Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()

return
```

however, the `removePosition()` does not have any effect on the target file.
Any idea ?